# why inc/hw_ints.h can not be opened?

Tags: c, microcontroller

Im trying to program a echo program using the tm4c1294nctpd and the HC-SR04 module.

I have done the next code, but when compiling it says that the /inc/hw_ints.h cannot be found

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sysctl.h>
#include <sysctl.c>
#include <inc/hw_ints.h>
#include <tm4c1294ncpdt.h>

    uint32_t i,CTA;

    void main(void){
            SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R=0X1008;
            i=SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DIR_R=0X01;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DEN_R=0X03;

            NVIC_EN0_R=0X08;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_IM_R  |=0X02;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_IS_R  =0X00;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_IEV_R |=0X02;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_ICR_R |=0X02;

            GPIO_PORTN_DIR_R  =0X03;
            GPIO_PORTN_DEN_R  =0X03;
            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R  =0X00;

            while (1)
                        {
                CTA=0;
                        GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R  ^=0X01;
                            SysCtlDelay(2666666);
                        GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R  |=0X01;
                            SysCtlDelay(100);
                    GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R  &=~0X01;
        }
    }

    int ECHO_ISR(void){
        while (((GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R & 0X02)== 0X02)& (CTA<0XFFF))
            {
                CTA++;
            }

            GPIO_PORTD_AHB_ICR_R |=0X02;
            return 0;
    }
```

I have to modify a bit the tm4c1294ncpdt_startup_ccs.c to add the ECHO_ISR in port D.
The error is pointed in the file sysctl.c, even when I explicit added in the #include section.

[image]
I have set the pats where it is  located in the properties of the project to include as

```
/home/user/ti/tivaware_c_series_2_1_4_178/driverlib
/home/user/ti/tivaware_c_series_2_1_4_178/inc
```

thanks

**Directories**
there is the standard code composer install under ti dir, inside this ti there is the tivaware and inside the tivaware the inc and driverlib, the hw_ints.h is in the inc directory
[image]
[image]

Paths set
[image]

Adding the path
[image]

Comment: `"inc/hw_ints.h"` or `<inc/hw_ints.h>`?

Comment: Both used and no luck

Comment: Is there such a file at all?

Comment: Yes indeed it is located in the inc directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following path as well:

```
/home/user/ti/tivaware_c_series_2_1_4_178
```

to your project properties and it should all work.

It is trying to find the `inc` folder, which you're in already, so add its parent.

Comment: @riccs_0x Try to switch between using double quotes and "<" ">" now. It should work.

Comment: @riccs_0x If that doesn't work, please show us your directory structure and it's source files

Comment: @riccs_0x Make sure to do a clean build as well

Comment: Im posting the dirs

Comment: @riccs_0x Now can you show us your project properties set paths?

Comment: @riccs_0x What you want is to go here https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/october/images/octarticle4.1.png (and make sure the path I mentioned is included under C, C/C++ and Assembly)

Comment: @riccs_0x Ah, you see, you're missing the path I told you to put in there. Add the path I specified under `Add dir to #include...`

Comment: Your screenshot does not show `/home/user/ti/tivaware_c_series_2_1_4_178` in the list of paths. Since `inc` is relative to it, it should be there. Either add this or remove the `inc` from the `#include` line

Comment: @John Even when I include it it does not compile

Comment: @riccs_0x This is becoming interesting. Can you show us what is the error now?

Comment: @John I just added it

Comment: @riccs_0x Try this: Restart your IDE, do a CLEAN build and show us the error in full.

Comment: @riccs_0x Perfect, now you have a different problem to solve. Let's have a look at your new error. Please include a full log.